# Piping a shell script to bash and launch interactive bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

Consider the following shell script on example.com

```
#/bin/bash

export HELLO_SCOPE=WORLD
eval $@
```

Now, I would like to download and then execute this shell script with parameters in the simplest way and be able to launch an interactive bash terminal with the HELLO_SCOPE variable set.

I have tried

```
curl http://example.com/hello_scope.sh | bash -s bash -i
```

But it quits the shell immediately. From what I can understand, it's because curls `stdout`, the script, remains the `stdin` of the bash, preventing it from starting interactively (as that would require my keyboard to be `stdin`).

Is there a way to avoid this without going through the extra step of creating a temporary file with the shell script?

Answer (score 7):

You can `source` it:

```
# open a shell
. <(curl http://example.com/hello_scope.sh)
# type commands ...
```

Comment: `bash <(curl http://example.com/hello_scope.sh)` if it should run in a subshell. With `source`, an `exit` will close the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You could just download this script you (using `wget` for example) and `source` this script, isn't it ?

```
script_name="hello_scope.sh"
[[ -f  $script_name ]] && rm -rf "$script_name"
wget "http://example.com/$script_name" -O "$script_name" -o /dev/null 
&& chmod u+x "$script_name" 
&& source "$script_name"
```

You could use `. "$script_name"` instead of `source "$script_name"` if you want (`.` is POSIX compliant). You could write the previous code in a script and `source` it to have interactive shell with the setted variable `$HELLO_SCOPE`.

Finally you could remove the `eval` line in your remote shell script.